# What are the steps to become an amateur operator in Canada?

Tags: license, canada

A little background. My uncle devoted part of his late life to ham radio, he had his callsign and would go install/fix radio systems all the time,travel across the country and would teach newcomers and lived the ham radio way and I'm thinking of following in the tradition he started.
Full disclosure: I know nothing at all about any of it and I'm for now researching to then decide the path to take.

Here is the question: How do I get a permit/license and get my own callsign to operate in Canada?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Radio Amateurs of Canada" national club seems to offer a number of resources and pointers on "How to Start" at [RAC](https://www.rac.ca/) and how to self-study. They also provide a list of local clubs; getting into contact with a club close to you may be a good alternative to starting and studying completely on your own.

Answer (score 1):

The following Government of Canada links may be of interest:

https://www.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/smt-gst.nsf/eng/h_sf01709.html

http://www.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/smt-gst.nsf/eng/h_sf06073.html

Good luck.